# Full calendar does not display events, but google receives request

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

I wrote my code below, I can see the calendar being displayed but not the events itself. It gets the events from Google Calendar. Now I feel like I am missing something, but when I go to the Google Developer Console next to my project name I see that request are going in but the same amount of errors also displays.
I got two questions

1. How can I see those errors?
2. Did I miss anything in my code?

```js
<html>
<head>

<link href="assets/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="assets/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.print.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media='print'>

<!----- jQuery and Moment must be loaded before FullCalendar's JavaScript. ----->
<script type='text/javascript' src='assets/fullcalendar/lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='assets/fullcalendar/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='assets/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='assets/fullcalendar/gcal.js'></script>


<script type='text/javascript'>
 $(document).ready(function() {
  // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...
  
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
   // put your options and callbacks here
   googleCalendarApiKey: 'AIzaSyCqhW82EulkhOCnAWMzLJuoaT2PzMvmIig',
   // Employee Calendar
   events: '0bhtj4inq9423divk026c6ags4@group.calendar.google.com',
   
   weekends: false, // will hide saturdays and Sundays
   header: {
    left: 'prev, next',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month',
   
   
   

   
    
  }
 });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>

<!-- div above displays Calendar -->
 <div id="calendar"></div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Instead of this line, events: '0bhtj4inq9423divk026c6ags4@group.calendar.google.com', change to googleCalendarId: 'abcd1234@group.calendar.google.com'. because that is calendar id.

Comment: so I changed it to.. 
events: {
        googleCalendarId: '0bhtj4inq9423divk026c6ags4@group.calendar.google.com'
}

nothing happens, I still see google gets the request but i get the same error on the developer console. 
The lastest fullCalendar 2.2.6 is v3 compatible right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem, it was the URL Pattern when you first create the public API. I was doing it wrong. I found a link in google that helped me. Once you open the website head to about 6/7 of the way down. you'll see the URL Pattern box.
https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/#cappingusage